# Group list of numpy arrays based on shape. Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have some instances of a class containing numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import os.path as osp
class Obj():
  def_init__(self, file):
     self.file = file
     self.data = np.fromfile(file)
     self.basename = osp.basename(file)
```

I have a list of such objects, which I want to group by shape. I can do that using sort:

```
obj_list = [obj1, obj2, ..., objn]
obj_list.sort(key=lambda obj: obj.data.shape)
```

Now I have a second list, say obj_list_2:
objects in obj_list_2 are initialized from different files but the resulting arrays have the same shape as in the first one (but not in the same order) and also the *basename*s are the same.

To clarify these are files loaded from different folders. In every folder I have the same files to which I applied different preprocessing)

If I sort them using the method shown above I can end up having

I want the two lists sorted based on shape and also **aligned according to their *basename***

I though about doing first a sort based on the shape followed by one based on *basename* (of a function of it). Something like

```
obj_list.sort(key=lambda obj: obj.data.shape)
obj_list.sort(key=lambda obj: obj.basename)
```

However the second sort might screw the first one. They should be done together, somehow.

### My final goal is to extract from the two lists the objects having the same shape and having the same basename

I tried with pandas but I'm not that familiar with it.
First I align them based on the *basename*, then I create a list of lists and pass it to pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
obj_list_of_list = [obj_list1, obj_list2]
obj_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(obj_list_of_list)
```

What is missing is to group them by shape and extract the different groups.

Comment: How about creating a dictionary with tuple keys `(shape, basename)`. Would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary mapping `(file, shape)` to a `list` of objects using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

obj_list = [obj1, obj2, ..., objn]

for obj in obj_list:
    d[(obj.filename, obj.data.shape)].append(obj)
```

Similarly, you can sort by shape *only* if you wish:

```
d_shape = defaultdict(list)

for obj in obj_list:
    d_shape[obj.data.shape].append(obj)
```

You can then access unique shapes via `d_shape.keys()`, and access a list of objects given a shape via `d_shape[some_shape]`. The benefit of such a solution is your complexity is O(n), while sorting will have higher complexity, e.g. O(*n* log *n*).

Comment: great! Thanks a lot.
I'd still like to know how that can be done in Pandas (so to learn).

Comment: Re: Pandas, to be honest, I don't think is well suited for this task. But maybe someone else may have an idea.